# Rails Model Method Not Working When Called in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with the following structure:

A `mealplan` includes one `recipe` for each day of the week, a `recipe` `has_many` `ingredients`, and a `grocery` is one item on the user's grocery list.

I have the following in my `mealplan.rb` model (WARNING: it is not very DRY.  My preemptive apologies):

```
class Mealplan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def add_to_grocery_list(current_user)
    @monday = Recipe.where(id: self.monday)[0]
    @tuesday = Recipe.where(id: self.tuesday)[0]
    @wednesday = Recipe.where(id: self.wednesday)[0]
    @thursday = Recipe.where(id: self.thursday)[0]
    @friday = Recipe.where(id: self.friday)[0]
    @saturday = Recipe.where(id: self.saturday)[0]
    @sunday = Recipe.where(id: self.sunday)[0]

    @monday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @tuesday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @wednesday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @thursday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @friday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @saturday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
    @sunday.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      if ingredient.listable
        Grocery.new(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, user_id: current_user.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then call this method in my `mealplan#create` and `mealplan#update` methods like this:

```
  def create
    @mealplan = Mealplan.new(mealplan_params)
    @mealplan.user_id = current_user.id
    @mealplan.add_to_grocery_list(current_user)

    if @mealplan.save
      redirect_to mealplans_path, notice: 'Mealplan was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /mealplans/1
  def update
    if @mealplan.update(mealplan_params)
      @mealplan.add_to_grocery_list(current_user)
      redirect_to mealplans_path, notice: 'Mealplan was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

When I actually create a `mealplan`, I don't get errors, but the `grocery` records don't get `create`d either.  Here's the server log:

```
Started POST "/mealplans" for ::1 at 2017-08-18 13:27:09 -0700
Processing by MealplansController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Rm6Wuh93HnX5gwGhGDthS5b7DmY0IbIhKShu7hagFaZzeqmmxbHTj/ixTqZn3Q9InfpxGeUcXKQvApG2+hcV6A==", "mealplan"=>{"week_starting(1i)"=>"2017", "week_starting(2i)"=>"8", "week_starting(3i)"=>"18", "monday"=>"5", "tuesday"=>"5", "wednesday"=>"5", "thursday"=>"4", "friday"=>"4", "saturday"=>"4", "sunday"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Create Mealplan"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", "5"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", "5"]]
  Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", "4"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", "4"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ?  [["id", "4"]]
  Ingredient Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 5]]
  Ingredient Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE "ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 4]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "mealplans" ("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday", "week_starting", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["monday", "5"], ["tuesday", "5"], ["wednesday", "5"], ["thursday", "4"], ["friday", "4"], ["saturday", "4"], ["sunday", "4"], ["week_starting", "2017-08-18"], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2017-08-18 20:27:09.248296"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-18 20:27:09.248296"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/mealplans
Completed 302 Found in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
```

Where am I going wrong here so the `add_to_grocery_list` method isn't working?  I'm not getting any errors, but the new `grocery` items aren't being created.

Comment: You say `Grocery.new` a bunch of places, but where do you say `Grocery.save`? Perhaps you want to do `Grocery.create` instead of `Grocery.new`?

Comment: @jvillian I thought `new` encompassed `save`, but with `create` you had to `save` separately....did I flip that around?

Comment: @jvillian, yes, apparently adding the `save` did the trick!  Thank you so much.  It's always the little stuff.  If you write up the answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Yes Liz it's the other way around. When you call .new you also must call .save in order to persist the records in db. You could use .create, as @jvillian suggested, which persists the record without calling .save (as long as model validations are satisfied, if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Grocery.new` you way to say `Grocery.create`. Right now, you're never saving the new `Grocery` record.